# How do Thestrals’ private parts work?

Tags: harry-potter

Are they like a horse? Or are they like birds’? Or what? And how do Thestrals do the deed?

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can I just ask why you want to know this?

Comment: We don't know and (hopefully) we will never know.

Comment: Hi close voters. About this being primarily opinion-based, "We don't know" isn't a reason to close. About this being unclear, please note that the close reason reads "unclear **what** you're asking", not "unclear **why** you're asking"... And in this case the "what" seems pretty clear, to me at least.

Comment: @F1Krazy You mean as opposed to all the very useful fantasy-related questions?

Answer (score 5):

Thestrals are described (by [JKR](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/thestrals)) as manifesting as

> **black, skeletal, bat-winged horses**,

and

> While somewhat intimidating in appearance, these **carnivorous horses** are emblematic of a journey to another dimension, and reward all who trust them with faithfulness and obedience. Thestrals are native to the British Isles and Ireland, though they have been spotted in parts of France and the Iberian Peninsula; they seem to have an association with wizards who descend from the horse-loving Celtic peoples. Other parts of the world have their own equivalent to Thestrals.

and in [Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them), they're referred to in the same breath as other less-exciting-sounding breeds.

> *“**Winged horses exist worldwide.** There are many different breeds, including the Abraxan (immensely powerful giant palominos), the Aethonan (chestnut, popular in Britain and Ireland), the Granian (grey and particularly fast) and the rare Thestral (black, possessed of the power of invisibility, and considered unlucky by many wizards).”*

I would assume that they procreate in precisely the same manner as non-carnivorous horses.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that last sentence?

Comment: @Adamant - Yes. When a mummy horse and a daddy horse love each other very much, they have a special horsey hug that they do to feel very close to each other.

Comment: Thank you for the information Valorum

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is specifically addressed anywhere, but perhaps we can make the following inference:

Throughout the books Thestrals are called "winged horses", for instance when Hagrid explains them to Umbridge:

> “Er — *Thestrals*!” he said loudly. “Big — er — winged
>   horses, yeh know!”

Similarly, in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* they are classified as a breed of Winged Horse. This may indicate that they are essentially horses and not birds. They are just magical horses that have wings.

Compare this to how other hybrid creatures are described. For instance, Hippogriffs are described in *Fantastic Beasts* as follows:

> It has the head of a giant eagle and the body of a horse.

In *Prisoner of Azkaban* they are described as:

> They had the bodies, hind legs, and tails of horses, but the front legs, wings, and heads of what seemed to be giant eagles, with cruel, steel-colored beaks and large, brilliantly orange eyes.

This does not sound like the description of a horse that magically has additional appendages; it sounds like the description of a creature that is fundamentally part horse and part eagle.

We find the same thing with sphinxes and centaurs. They seem to truly be part human and part horse/lion.

If Thestrals are fundamentally horses then we might assume that their procreation (and organs thereof) is like that of a horse, and not a bird.

Answer (score -1):

**Their genitals are not addressed.**

The reason they are not addressed is because the primary target audience of the books are children. When writing books for children, authors generally make sure not to describe genitals.

It is very unlikely that we will get information on anyone's genitals from Rowling. There is no scenario in which this would be beneficial to her, and she is likely well aware of that.

Comment: I'm assuming Hagrid's *"Dragon-Breeding for Pleasure and Profit"* would address the sticky business of how dragon eggs are made.

Comment: @Valorum I suppose if Rowling ever publishes the book complete with a description of dragon gentians, I'll be happy to include a caveat in my answer. That said, it'll make it even less likely that Thestral genitals will star at any point. A children's book that describes a set of genitals may be unusual - but a children's book that keeps on describing more genitals is really asking for trouble.